# append() not working corretly in IF statement

Tags: python-3.x

Im only about a month into python so still learning and I cant see a similar question or more like problem. I have a list and dictionary that I want to add new entries to. When I run this code:

```
n = input('Enter variable name to check: ')

varDict = {} #Key = label and Value = description
valList = [] #Lists the referenced values from the code

if n in varDict:
    print(varDict[n])
    print(valList[n])

if n not in varDict:
    new = input('Not found, make new entry?')
    if new == 'yes':
        desc = input('Enter description: ')
        varDict[n] = desc
        valList.append(n)
        print(n, 'has been added to the list')
    elif new == 'no':
            print('Done')
```

it seems to work fine, but when you re-run the code and enter new values, it overrides the first entry in the list and dictionary instead of adding new entries in both. Ive also googled this and my code seems 100% fine, but it just keeps the list and dict's length at 1 entry.

Im not sure what the problem is and any help would be great, thanks.

EDIT: I added the full code.

Comment: What is `n`? Where do you change it?

Comment: This is not a [mcve]

Comment: Use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) to save and restore `varDict` and `valList` from a file, otherwise the current values will be lost every time the script finishes.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a python program whatever data you put in is temperary, as it only is saved to variables while you're running it.
So when you rerun this program, and aren't seeing what you last entered in, that's purely python's functionality, as it is with every other (scripting) programming language.
If you want to keep these values, think about adding them to a file (learn `open()`) and retrieving them at the start of the program and putting them into the variables (`varDict`, `valList`) before asking for user input.